Impact of Schottky Barrier Height on the Performance of High Electron Mobility Transistors (HEMTs)
In the context of High Electron Mobility Transistors (HEMTs), the Schottky barrier height (SBH) plays a crucial role in determining the device's overall performance, particularly its electrical characteristics. From a general perspective, would a high or low SBH be more favorable for optimizing the performance of HEMTs, especially in terms of current conduction, electron mobility, and device efficiency?
I understand that the Schottky barrier influences the source-to-channel contact resistance, but I am looking for a broader explanation in terms of its impact on HEMT performance. Could you elaborate on the trade-offs involved with different SBH values, and how they relate to the fundamental principles of HEMT operation?

It seems that you want a general tutorial of the influence of the Schottky barrier height on the "performance" of a HEMT. This can be easily found in  textbooks and lecture notes. Maybe you should be more specific with your question and state what your state of knowledge is and what specifically you want to know.

Thank you for your response; do you have any suggestions?
